# Accessing core web pages from multiple directories

Tags: html, web

It's tough to write a cohesive title for the issue I'm having here, so I'll try my best to explain it here.

I have one domain, and within that domain will be six sub-directories (domain.com/site1, domain.com/site2, etc.).  The six sites will have the same makeup and same content, so the key content pages will be in other directories.  The differences between each of the six sites is aesthetics, so I was going to have PHP dynamically add the second stylesheet (with the site-specific styles) depending on which directory is accessed to achieve that.

Now, the issue I'm having is this.  Suppose you are at domain.com/site1 and you click into a content page.  The content pages exist only once, and to avoid having the same files six times, they are kept in a separate directory outside of the six site directories from before (so, domain.com/content1, domain.com/content2, etc.).  I want the URL that's displayed to stay within the site directory I'm at, while loading that content (if I'm in site1 and click a link to some content, I'll go to domain.com/site1/content1/page.php instead of domain.com/content1/page.php).  That way if you are viewing the content, you're still within the site you started off in.

I hope what I'm asking for makes sense.  I can try my best to clarify further if needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `include` and `include_once`, which directly add the text from a specified file as if it was PHP and/or HTML code.

For more information, check out http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include-once.php

Comment: I already have includes for the header/footer type of stuff.  For the content pages though, it's important to have the unique URL for each, so I don't see how include statements would help here.  The idea is to avoid multiple copies of the same page.  Includes would work... but then I'd still have six files, each with an include statement on them.

Comment: You can't really do less... To have `www.domain.com/myDir` as the directory, you have to be on a page in that directory. If you include your content from another directory, then it is possible.

Comment: So you're saying this is the best way to achieve what I'm asking?  I just want to make sure before I set forth on this and find out later there is a more efficient way.  Thanks.

Comment: I must admit _I_ can't see better. Doesn't mean there isn't better. I'd recommend doing a back up then trying that solution.

Comment: Can always chalk it up to a "phase two".  Thanks, appreciate the help.